# Add Summary Toolbar programmatically to a ListViewWebPart in SharePoint 2010

Tags: listview, sharepoint, toolbar, summary

I have a Listview Web Part on my homepage showing some announcements from an announcement list. Instead of going to the list in All site content each time to add a new announcement, I want to do it directly from the Web Part on my homepage. I changed the Web Part directly from the browser and saw that it is called "Summary Toolbar". So the question is, how do I get the same result programmatically?

My code for the Web Part:

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared
ListViewWebPart announcementListWP = new ListViewWebPart();
SPList customLists = web.Lists[StringConstants.ANNOUNCEMENTS];

announcementListWP.ChromeType = PartChromeType.Default;
announcementListWP.Title = "Announcements Web Part";
announcementListWP.ListName = customLists.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
announcementListWP.ViewGuid = customLists.Views[StringConstants.DISPLAYVIEW].ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();

customLists.Update();

mgr.AddWebPart(newsListWP, "Right", 1);
mgr.SaveChanges(newsListWP);

web.Update();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **xsltlistviewwebpart** instead of list view and set toolbar to fulltoolbar/summary toolbar.
Which will give you *Add New Item* link ,you can add items on same page no need to navigte to view all sitecontent ,lists and add items